# Create a map which has integer as key and an enum as values

Tags: java, enums

How to create map in java with integer as key and enum as value?

Comment: Add Your Code , That You had tried so far.

Comment: BTW, if the index is an `Integer`, you should really use a `List`.

Comment: Exactly like any other map?

Comment: @BackSlash That depends on the distribution of the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
enum Color {
    RED,BLUE,GREEN
}

Map<Integer, Color> map= new HashMap<Integer, Color>();
           map.put(1, Color.RED);
           map.put(2, Color.BLUE);
           map.put(3, Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: can you give me a clear solution.. like an example code in which I can test

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
 Map<Integer,yourEnum>m=new HashMap<Integer,yourEnum>();
```